# How to set localAddress in fetch request in node.js?

Tags: node.js, ip, fetch-api

On my server i have multiple ip addresses.
I need to make API call from my node.js server to external service, but i need to make it from specific ip address each time (the ip depend on many factors).

it seems that `HTTP` module of node support `localAddress` property to specify from what ip address send the request but some library I import use the fetch method.

How i can tell `fetch` method to make http request from a specific ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `fetch` in Node.js you mean `node-fetch` npm module, then, judging by the fact that it interprets it's own `options` object and builds an entirely different one for the `http.get` request it wraps (all so that it can match the WHATWG Fetch Specification more fully), unfortunately it's impossible. Furthermore, this functionality would/could never be part of any browser API.

You can, however use the `localAdress` in `options` object with `got` npm module, which is a much more transparent Promise wrapper around `http.request`.

More details about the syntax:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/got
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback